# How do I access string of json object in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make an app that displays quotes from a famous person (e.g.  Bob Dylan) using the wiki quote api.

The request url looks like this:

```
https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=Bob_Dylan&prop=text
```

I have the React Native request working with:

```
componentWillMount() {
Api().then((response) => {
  this.setState({
    quote:response.parse.text

  })

});
}
```

When I try to display the quote, however, it is in the form of an object and get [object object] in the view. In the console I receive:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {*}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Text`.
>   Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {*}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Text`.

When I try `response.parse.text.*` I receive a token error. Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Comment: `response.parse.text['*']` .. `*` is a special character

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly turn `response` into `Object` , by calling its `json()` method, like:

```
 var url = 'https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=Bob_Dylan&prop=text';

 fetch(url)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .catch((error) => console.warn("fetch error:", error))
   .then((response) => console.log(response.parse))
```

Working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/EqyMdA

Answer (score 0):

You can use response.text() instead of response.json()

```
var url = 'https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?
 fetch(url)
   .then((response) => response.text())
   .catch((error) => console.warn("fetch error:", error))
   .then((response) => console.log(response.parse))
```